# Find document in joined collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to search in both collection from a field but I don't succeed. I succeed to search in the first collection but in the second I can't.

This are my collections

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
 { category: String }
)

const appSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  { 
    category: { 
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'Category'
    },
    name: String
  }
)
```

How I want to receive data filtered by `req.query.q`

```
http://localhost:6000/q="test 1"
or
http://localhost:6000/q="app"

{
  category: 'Test 1'
  apps: [
    { name: 'App1'},
    { name: 'App2'}
  ]
}
```

What I tried

```
const getApps = async (req, res) => {
   Category.aggregate([
    {
     $match: {
      category: { $regex: req.query.q, $options: 'i' }
     }
    },
    {
     $lookup: {
      from: 'app',
      as: 'apps',
      let: { category: "$_id"},
      pipeline: [
       { 
         $match: {
          $expr: { $eq: ['$category', '$$category'] }
         }
       }
      ]
     }
   }
 ])
}
```

I cannot filter items in AppSchema by `req.query.q` only in CategorySchema I can. How can I filter both by `req.query.q`. Sorry for my english

Comment: please add sample input

Comment: I don't understand what simple input to add. I want to search in both collections (Category and App) by a parameter and the result to be like the one above.

Comment: is this what do you want? https://mongoplayground.net/p/G_vGdA-Cvfn

Comment: The aggregation works as expected: https://mongoplayground.net/p/9Fbts7VaXqh

Comment: But how I search for the apps? I want to search for both category and app not only for category

Comment: Ah ok, you can do something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/EjwWUovEJAx

Comment: @Fraction thank you this is what I want, but I need to do like an "OR" between those two. If I search for example "App 1" first search in  Category is not exists then to search in App. In your example first is search in Category. If category not exists will return nothing.

Comment: You can try using the [$or (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) operator within the `$expr`.